# How to open Save File Dialog in JavaScript for Firebase files

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

My issue is I am using Firebase storage to upload and download files. Everything is working fine except I need Save file Dialog box to download files. Currently the browser is opening those files in current tab though the files which browser is not capable of reading are triggering Save Dialog.

Here is the code I am using for uploading files

```
function uploadFileAsPromise (file, attachments, index) {
var metadata = {
    contentDisposition: 'attachment; filename=\"'+(moment().unix()+file.name)+'\"',
};

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var storageRef = storage.ref("attachments/"+(moment().unix()+file.name));

    //Upload file
    var task = storageRef.put(file);

    //Update progress bar
    task.on('state_changed',
       //listeners 
    );
});
}
```

Here is the code in html which is supposed to give me Save Dialog.

```
<a download href="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sf-firestore.appspot.com/o/attachments%2F1546685444Capture.PNG?alt=media&amp;token=60562b91-0cd8-420b-b345-0c6af937f259" class="selected-files">
  </a>
```

Comment: It would be better to create an answer for your question yourself, rather than updating the question with the answer!

Comment: Ideally, titles are a succinct description of the problem, whereas "JavaScript Firebase Save File Dialog" is only set of tags that hint at the general theme. Ideally, if you can ask along the lines of "How to foo the bar in a widget", you will have a very useful title.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, all noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I forgot to pass metadata in put statement like below

```
var task = storageRef.put(file, metadata);
```

It's working now.